# Returning all components multiple levels under a parent component

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical database out of which I would like to return all components in an asset with a *specific* common parent component.

Components in table `astComponents` are linked to their parent components with a `ParentComponentId` referring to the `Id` of other components. This, however, only shows the parent one level up.

Additionally, all components are linked to an asset by an `AssetId` key, linking to the `Id` key in table `astAssets`.

I am able to make a simple query (below) to retrieve all components from a specific asset. I can't figure out how to return all components from a specific asset sharing the same parent component. This parent component may (relative to a child component) 1 to multiple levels up.

```
Select C.Id, C.Code, ParentC.Id, ParentC.Code, A.Code
From astComponents C

Join astAssets A ON A.Id = C.AssetId
Join astComponents ParentC ON ParentC.Id = C.ParentComponentId

Where A.Code = '2018100000'
```

The above query returns components and their parents one level up. Were I to specify the parent code, it would only return the child components one level below this specified component, instead of all levels down.

Comment: You wrote _specific_ parent component. Can we assume that you know that component in advance?

Comment: @user1429080 I sure do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, without any data to work with there's a lot of guesswork going on here.  I created some data:

```
DECLARE @astComponents TABLE (Id INT, Code VARCHAR(50), ParentComponentId INT, AssetId INT);
DECLARE @astAssets TABLE (Id INT, Code VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @astAssets SELECT 1, '2018100000';
INSERT INTO @astAssets SELECT 2, '2018100001';
INSERT INTO @astComponents SELECT 1, 'Power Supply', NULL, 1;
INSERT INTO @astComponents SELECT 2, 'Fan', 1, NULL;
INSERT INTO @astComponents SELECT 3, 'Screw', 2, NULL;
INSERT INTO @astComponents SELECT 4, 'Heat Tape', 1, NULL;
INSERT INTO @astComponents SELECT 5, 'Magnet', NULL, 2;
INSERT INTO @astComponents SELECT 6, 'Iron', 5, NULL;
```

What you can do with this is to use recursion to map out all the components that share a common parent, and record which asset they belong to, e.g.:

```
--Make a recursive list of components sharing a common parent
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Id,
        ParentComponentId,
        AssetId
    FROM
        @astComponents
    WHERE
        ParentComponentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c.Id,
        c.ParentComponentId,
        cte.AssetId
    FROM
        @astComponents c
        INNER JOIN cte ON cte.Id = c.ParentComponentId)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

I bet your tables don't work like this, so you would need to tweak this to suit.  In my case I get the following results:

```
Id  ParentComponentId   AssetId
1       NULL        1
5       NULL        2
6       5           2
2       1           1
4       1           1
3       2           1
```

So I can see that components #1 and #5 have no parents, so these are "top level" components, and I can also see which components link to which assets.

Now it's simply a case of replacing the `SELECT * FROM cte` part of my query with something like this:

```
SELECT 
    cte.Id,
    c.Code,
    c.ParentComponentId
FROM 
    cte
    INNER JOIN @astComponents c ON c.Id = cte.Id
    INNER JOIN @astAssets a ON a.Id = cte.AssetId
WHERE
    a.Code = '2018100000';
```

Gives me all the components that share a parent where the parent has an asset code of 201810000:

```
Id  Code    ParentComponentId
1   Power Supply    NULL
2   Fan 1
4   Heat Tape   1
3   Screw   2
```

Comment: Excellent! Tweaked your cte with `WHERE
        ParentComponentId = 33639073` and later joined the `astComponents` table like you did. Joining the `astAssets` table deemed to be unnecessary as the parent component is already only present in that specific asset, as by design.

Answer (score 0):

So if I have understood this correctly, you have a known parent component, *and* a known asset code. Using them you want to build a tree covering the *paths* (for lack of a better word) from the parent component to the asset in question?

Here's an attempt to do that. We start by just building some dummy data to use for testing:

```
declare @component table (
    id int primary key,
    code nvarchar(50) not null,
    parent_id int null,
    asset_id int null
)
declare @asset table (
    id int primary key,
    code nvarchar(50)
)

insert into @asset values (1, '2018100000')
insert into @asset values (2, '2019100000')

insert into @component values(1, 'root', null, null)
insert into @component values(2, 'c1', 1, null)
insert into @component values(3, 'c2', 1, null)
insert into @component values(4, 'c3', 1, null)
insert into @component values(5, 'c2_c1', 3, null)
insert into @component values(6, 'c2_c2', 3, 1)
insert into @component values(7, 'c2_c1_c1', 5, 2)
insert into @component values(8, 'c2_c1_c2', 5, 1)
insert into @component values(9, 'c2_c1_c2_c1', 8, 2)
insert into @component values(9, 'c2_c1_c1_c1', 7, 1)
```

Then we declare a couple of recursive `CTE`:s and use them to get the output:

```
declare @specParentId int
declare @assetCode nvarchar(50)
set @specParentId = 3
set @assetCode = '2018100000'

;with compRecurseDown as (
    select c.id, c.code, parent_id, 0 as level, c.asset_id
    from @component c
    where c.id = @specParentId

    union all

    select c.id, c.code, c.parent_id, p.level + 1, c.asset_id
    from @component c
        join compRecurseDown p on c.parent_id = p.id
), assetRecurseUp as (
    select c.*
    from @asset a
        join @component c on a.id = c.asset_id
    where a.code = @assetCode

    union all 

    select c.*
    from @component c
        join assetRecurseUp p on p.parent_id = c.id
)
select crd.*, a.code as asset_code
from compRecurseDown crd
    left outer join @asset a on crd.asset_id = a.id
where crd.id in (
    select id from assetRecurseUp
)
order by level
```

In this case we are looking for asset `2018100000` under the component with id `3`. Result:

```
| id | code     | parent_id | level | asset_id | asset_code | 
|----|----------|-----------|-------|----------|------------| 
| 3  | c2       | 1         | 0     | NULL     | NULL       | 
| 5  | c2_c1    | 3         | 1     | NULL     | NULL       | 
| 6  | c2_c2    | 3         | 1     | 1        | 2018100000 | 
| 8  | c2_c1_c2 | 5         | 2     | 1        | 2018100000 |
```

So how does this work? First we declare the `compRecurseDown` CTE. It uses the known parent component as its `anchor`, then recursively finds all child notes under this node.

The `assetRecurseUp` CTE starts by finding all components linked to the known asset. Then it recursively adds all parent nodes based on that.

Finally we query the combination of these two to produce the final result set.

Comment: Trying to [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61b5e/5) my way through this but after I got through the errors I am getting zero records